# Send recaptcha secret in POST body instead of URL parameters

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

Server Integration of ReCaptcha works well when I pass values as URL parameters.

```
{
  "success": false,
  "error-codes": [
    "missing-input-response",
    "missing-input-secret"
  ]
}
```

The request fails when I pass values as JSON in POST body.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "challenge_ts": "2018-10-26T16:01:24Z",
  "hostname": "testkey.google.com"
}
```

Sample code I have seen so far suggests using URL parameters but does not explain why JSON POST body is not supported.

[Google's FAQ](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq) does not list it either, I am wondering if I am doing something wrong. Is it even possible to request through JSON?

Answer (score 5):

Google's recaptcha api does not support json body. They expect you to send the body as query params.

For example:

- **POST** request.
- **Body**: 'secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&response=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
- **Header**: 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Would you know or has recaptcha stated why json body is not supported?

Comment: If you asked why JSON body is not supported then it's how google decided.